# Anti-concentration inequality for the eigenvalue of Gaussian matrix

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, measure-concentration

Let $f(x) = f(x_1, . . . , x_n)$ be a polynomial of degree $d$ and $\text{Var}[f] = 1$. One result by Carbery and Wright shows that for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $ε > 0$,
$$
\text{Pr}_{x\sim N^n}[|f(x) − t| ≤ ε] ≤ O(d)  ε^{1/d}\label{1}\tag{$\color{red}{\star}$}
$$ and there are some simplified proofs (eg. [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.05992)).

**My questions**:

1. Is there any related results about the anti-concentration of the eigenvalues of a random matrix?
2. For a real symmetric matrix whose entries are normal variables, can we bound the term
   $$
   \text{Pr}[|\lambda_i-t|\leq\epsilon]
   $$ where $\lambda_i$ is some eigenvalue (or more specifically, the smallest/largest,etc)?
3. Apparently the eigenvalue may not be a polynomial of its entries so we can't directly use the above result. Is there any research or literature about this problem?

---

<sub>\eqref{1} Carbery A, Wright J. Distributional and $ L^{q} $ norm inequalities for polynomials over convex bodies in ${\Bbb R}^ n$[J]. Mathematical Research Letters, 2001, 8(3): 233-248, [MR1839474](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1839474), [Zbl 0989.26010](https://zbmath.org/0989.26010).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Theorem 2 in

> Iain M. Johnstone. Zongming Ma. "Fast approach to the Tracy–Widom law at the edge of GOE and GUE." Ann. Appl. Probab. 22 (5) 1962 - 1988, October 2012. https://doi.org/10.1214/11-AAP819

gives, for the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of a GOE matrix of size $N$, that there exists $C=C(s_0)$ such that for any real $s\ge s_0$,
$$
|P\Big((\lambda_1 - \sqrt{2N+1})/(2^{-1/2}n^{-1/6})\le s \Big) - F_1(s)| \le C N^{-2/3} e^{-s/2}
$$
where $F_1(s)$ is the CDF of the Tracy-Widom law for $\beta=1$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracy%E2%80%93Widom_distribution).
Small ball probabilities can then be obtained using bounds on the density of $F_1$.